# Using where in inner join of 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

I want to get list of trains available on a particular date between a pair of stations:
These are my tables.

```
`route` 
(
    `train_id`,
    `Stop_number`,
    `Station_id`,
    `Arrival_time`,
    `Departure_time`,
    `Source_distance`
)

`train` 
(
    `Train_id`,
    `Train_name`,
    `Train_type`,
    `Source_station`,
    `Destination_Station`,
    `Source_id`,
    `Destination_id`
)


`train_status` 
(
    `Train_id`,
    `Available_date`,
    `Booked_seat`,
    `Waiting_seat`,
    `Available_seat`
)
```

I am creating a mysql database for railway reservation system.
I am new to mysql but still tried to write this query using inner joins .
Please help me work this query.

```
    Select Route.Train_id, Train.Train_name, Train_status.Available_date
    FROM Route INNER JOIN  Train 
    ON Route.Train_id = Train.Train_id
    INNER JOIN 
    Train_status ON   Train.Train_id= Train_status.Train_id
    WHERE       (Route.Station_id IN
                (Select Source.Station_id
                    FROM    Route AS Source INNER JOIN
                           Route AS Destination ON Source.Train_id=
    Destination.Train_id WHERE      (Source.Stop_number-Destination.Stop_number<0)AND
    (Source.Station_id=@Source) AND  (Destination.Station_id=@Dest) )) AND 
        (Train_status.Available_Date = @Available_Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is similar try it and let me know if this works or not:

```
Select Route.train_id, Train.Train_name, Train_status.Available_date
FROM Train
INNER JOIN Train_status ON   Train.Train_id= Train_status.Train_id AND Train_status.Available_Date = @Available_Date
INNER JOIN Route AS Source ON Source.Train_id=Train.Train_id and Source.Station_id=@Source
INNER JOIN Route AS Destination ON Destination.Train_id=Train.Train_id and Destination.Station_id=@Dest
```

Comment: I agree with the basic idea, but you have an extra ON clause on the FROM

Comment: While refactoring query that was missed to edit...I corrected it...thanks

Comment: it gives an error as:     Unknown column 'Route.Train_id' in 'field list'

Comment: check the column name, it should have same column name considering uppercase and lowercase. in your query you have written Route.Train_id while column name is Select Route.train_id. Make change and it will work.

Comment: @krishnaaryal  i edited the column name to Train_id but still the same error....tried breaking down the query to only train name and available date....it works but without route.Train_id.

Comment: do i have to drop route table and create it again....or the problem lies in the last part where we inner join route table twice...

Comment: its not route.Train_id its route.train_id according to the details you have given above

Comment: I did what u had told...And it works just fine...Thank you@krishna aryal